# Cassandra data modeling timeseries data

Tags: cassandra, analytics, spark-cassandra-connector

I have this data about visited users for an app/service:

```
contentId (assume uuid), 
platform (eg. website, mobile etc), 
softwareVersion (eg. sw1.1, sw2.5, ..etc),
regionId (eg. us144, uk123, etc..)
....
```

I have modeled it very simply like
id(String)               time(Date)       count(int)
contentid1-sw1.1         Feb06            30
contentid1-sw2.1         Feb06            20
contentid1-sw1.1         Feb07            10
contentid1-sw2.1         Feb07            10
contentid1-us144         Feb06            23
contentid1-sw1.1-us144   Feb06            10
....

Reason is because there's a popular query where someone can ask for contentId=foo,platform=bar,regionId=baz or any combination of those for a range of time (say between Jan 01 - Feb 05).

But another query that's not easily answerable is:

Return top K 'platform' for contentId=foo between Jan01 - Feb05. By top it means to be sorted by 'count's in that range. So for above data, query for top 2 platforms for contentId=contentId1 between Feb6-Feb8 must return:

```
sw1.1   40
sw2.1   30
```

Not sure how to model that in C* to get answers for top K queries, anyone has any ideas?

PS: there are 1billion+ entries for each day.
Also I am open to using Spark or any other frameworks along with C* to get these answers.

Comment: you have to make use of clustering key , and as specified you need result in specific order of COUNT column then your key should contains count .what is your current table structure

Comment: since the requirement is to query on time range, 'time' is my clustering key.  id is '-' separated strings as 'contentid1-sw2.1'. This is how it is right now:  ( 
 id text,
 time timestamp, 
 count double,
 PRIMARY KEY (id, time)
)